# Postgres Insert if not exists, Update if exists on non-unique column?

Tags: postgresql

I am currently using `ON CONFLICT SET` to update if there's a duplicate value on a unique column.

```
INSERT INTO `table`(col1, col2) VALUES ('v1', 'v2') 
ON CONFLICT (col1)
DO UPDATE SET
col2 = 'v3'
```

From the example, `col1` is a unique field. But how do I do this if `col1` is not unique?

I tried without the unique constraint now I'm getting:

```
Invalid column reference: 7 ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using 2 successive queries. (1) Try to update first, if no rows updated, (2) try to insert.

In php:

```php
// Try update
$return = execute("UPDATE table SET ... WHERE ...col1='unique_value'...");

// If update returns no value, insert
if (!$return) {
    execute("
        INSERT INTO table (...)
            SELECT ...values...
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ...col1='unique_value'...)
    ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the very definition you cannot have a conflict on a non-unique column. But since you do not duplicates just make it unique.

```
Alter table "table" add constraint col1_uk unique(col1);
```

Comment: Not an option, the `col1` here really isn't unique. There are just some modules that requires this part to only have 1 `col1`. Quite hard to explain the details